# How to make argument by closure?

Tags: swift

I have an error when call the func that argument is closure.

Here is my code:

```
 func animateSwap(swap: Swap, completion: () -> () = {}) {

    let spriteA = swap.cookieA.sprite!
    let spriteB = swap.cookieB.sprite!

    spriteA.zPosition = 100
    spriteB.zPosition = 90

    let Duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.3

    let moveA = SKAction.moveTo(spriteB.position, duration: Duration)
    spriteA.runAction(moveA, completion: completion)

    let moveB = SKAction.moveTo(spriteA.position, duration: Duration)
    spriteB.runAction(moveB)

}
```

When I call the func like that

```
 scene.animateSwap(swap, completion: handleMatches()){

       }
```

I have an a error:

> Extra argument 'completion' in call

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the `completion` is wrong for your purposes. Replace your first line with:

```
func animateSwap(swap: Swap, completion: (() -> Void)?) -> () {
```

and add `return completion!()` to the end of the function. However, this means that you can't run the function with `completion: nil`, so you might as well check if the completion is nil before returning it.

and use it like this:

```
scene.animateSwap(swap, completion: {
    // All code here will be run on completion
    handleMatches()
})
```

Comment: Hi dzk
Thanks for your answer.